# Headless osgi / rcp application

Tags: maven, osgi, rcp, tycho, headless

I have an OSGi based RCP app. We use maven and tycho to deploy our features and plugins and use them in product. I want to start all bundles/plugins in this product apart from the workbench (head) ones. I have tried search online, but no luck. All tutorials use [Buckminster](http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/) or PDE tooling, neither of which works for me and my team.  Any help or leads are much appreciated.

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here.

Comment: I want to build a headless RCP app, tried looking online but I am unable to find one. 
Question is: is there a way to start all bundles in osgi  apart from workbench from cmd, such that everything is loaded and in memory and then workbench ui can be fired up as and when required ?

Comment: No, the workbench UI is started by the bundles. You would have to start an OSGi Framework without those workbench bundles.

Comment: @NeilBartlett thanks for the tip. Let me try doing that.

Comment: You can also add custom application that you register with the corresponding extension point and that don't start the UI. Eclipse uses this mechanism to offer headless command line tools that you can run to [publish p2 metadata](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_publisher.html)